# Return list of new custom-class objects in python C API

Tags: python, pointers, swig, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I need to create a new list via the python C API containing new copies of objects of a `Quaternion` class I've written (in C++).  [Actually, [I'd really like a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532871/creating-a-numpy-array-of-custom-class-objects-with-c-api), but any sort of sequence would do.]  But I'm getting seg faults with everything I've tried.  I'm terrible with pointers, so that's not a big surprise.  I'm thinking maybe I need to give python ownership of the objects I create with `new`.

The best I've gotten so far appears below.  Am I not supposed to copy-construct the Quaternion while `new`ing it?  Am I doing something else stupid?  Do I need to tell python it owns the reference now?  Should the returned list exist and live a happy life, as I expected?

```
PyObject* Objectify(std::vector<Quaternion>& v) {
  Py_ssize_t size = v.size();
  PyArrayObject* list = (PyArrayObject*) PyList_New(size);
  for(Py_ssize_t i=0; i<size; ++i) {
    PyObject* o = (PyObject*) new Quaternion(v[i]);
    PyList_SET_ITEM((PyObject*)list, i, o);
  }
  return PyArray_Return(list);
}
```

I can verify that the list still has the correct elements just before the return.  That is, after the loop above, I make a new loop and print out the original values next to the list values, and they match.  The function will return, and I can keep using python.  But once the list is used outside the loop, the segfaults happen.

[Actually, this is all being done in SWIG, and this code is found in a typemap with slightly different variable names, but I can look in the `_wrap.cxx` file, and see that it's just how I would have written it.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I see it, it's obvious.  I can't just cast an arbitrary type to a `PyObject`; it needs to actually have some actual python structure.  E.g., I'm thinking a `PyArrayObject` can be cast as such, but my random class needs to be wrapped, as dastrobu explained on my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532871/creating-a-numpy-array-of-custom-class-objects-with-c-api).

As I mentioned, I'm using SWIG, which already wraps `Quaternion` into some kind of `PyObject` (though it's given some other name to denote that it's made by SWIG).  So, while this doesn't answer my question in general, the following does exactly what I need (including creating numpy arrays, rather than just lists):

```
npy_intp size = v.size();
PyArrayObject *npy_arr = reinterpret_cast<PyArrayObject*>(PyArray_SimpleNew(1, &size, NPY_OBJECT));
PyObject** data = static_cast<PyObject**>(PyArray_DATA(npy_arr));
for(npy_intp i=0; i<size; ++i) {
  PyObject* qobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj((new Quaternions::Quaternion(v[i])),
                                      SWIGTYPE_p_Quaternions__Quaternion, SWIG_POINTER_OWN);
  if(!qobj) {SWIG_fail;}
  data[i] = qobj;
  Py_INCREF(qobj);
}
```

I should also point out that I originally tried using `PyArray_SET_ITEM` to assign the items of the list in this code, but kept getting segfaults, which is why I use this weird method.  I wonder if it has something to do with the offsets of the `NPY_OBJECT`...

Anyway, I hope that helps someone else in the future.